# VBA Sigma Formula With Factorial

Tags: excel, vba, algebra

[image]
Need to count sigma with x = 0.7

Thats my version of code, but it doesnt work properly, need help:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()


Dim k As Long
Dim Numerator As Double
Dim Result As Double

x = 0.7
For k = 0 To infinity Step 1
    Numerator = 0
    Numerator = Numerator + (-1) ^ (k + 1) * x ^ (2 * k - 1)
Next k
Result = Result + Numerator / Application.WorksheetFunction.Fact((2 * k - 1) * (2 * k + 1))

Debug.Print Result
    
End Sub
```

I get Run-time error "1004" in result line.

Comment: Not regarding your specific error, but how do you expect code to loop to infinity and produce a result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few changes to your code:

1. Used `n` for the number of terms in a partial sum rather than `infinity`
2. It is now a function of `x` and `n` rather than a sub
3. The unnecessary `Step 1` in the for loop has been dropped
4. The `2*k-1` factor has moved outside the factorial
5. `Fact` has been replaced by `FactDouble` to guard against overflow
6. The numerators are not added together independent of the denominators. Instead, a fraction is added at each step.

Here is the code:

```
Function Sigma(x As Double, n As Long) As Double
    Dim i As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim Numerator As Double
    Dim Denominator As Double
    Dim Sum As Double
    
    For k = 0 To n
        Numerator = (-1) ^ (k + 1) * x ^ (2 * k - 1)
        Denominator = (2 * k - 1) * Application.WorksheetFunction.FactDouble(2 * k + 1)
        Sum = Sum + Numerator / Denominator
    Next k
    Sigma = Sum
End Function
```

For example

```
Sub test()
    Debug.Print Sigma(0.7, 20)
End Sub
```

Which prints `1.65459064177857`